# MvvmCross and complex navigation

Tags: navigation, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have difficulties in understanding, how would mvvmcross navigation work in some more complex situations. Let's take app, that we want to make for WP7 and Metro using mvvmcross as base. We create three view model's (**FirstViewModel, SecondViewModel, ThirdVIewModel**), fill them with some data and use regular navigation to move between them (using **ShowViewModel()** methods). So far this works well and we want exacly this kind of navigation on Windows Phone device, which is three separate views, that we can navigate back and forth.

Now looking from Metro app perspective - we have much larger screen, usually used in lanscape mode, so we decide we would like to have the content of this three pages showed as one single page.

Here is where I see the problem - because both versions of app use the same Core and the same view models hierarchy - it seems impossible to have this kind of behaviour at the same time. Navigation from FirstViewModel to SecondViewModel does not apply to Metro version of app, because we are in fact on first screen which we want to contains all the data from all three view models. On the opposite side - we cant put those three view models inside bigger one and use it as single view model, because those three separate view models along with regular navigation works well for us on Windows Phone.

Is there a way to provide such non standard navigation using mvvmcross? If so, is it some simple code that's needs to be overrwritten/added (that I don't see, maybe?), or rather complex stuff, requiring considerable amount of time and coding to enable this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 2):

MvvmCross has different ways to change its default mechanism.
A good place to start is the Wiki: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup

**Regarding your example:**

One idea I have is create a MainViewModel which contains all the three view-models for the WindowStore app.

You can still have MainViewModel in Core project even if it's used only by Windows Store app. You might want to use it later for Android or iOS tablet app too:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public FirstViewModel First { get; private set; }
    public SecondViewModel Second { get; private set; }
    public ThirdViewModel Third { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
          this.First = new FirstViewModel();
          this.Second = new SecondViewModel();
          this.Third = new ThirdViewModel();
     }
}
```

**Next, depending on platform you need to either navigate to MainViewModel or FirstViewModel**.

There are few ways to do that in MvvmCross.

One option is have a CustomAppStart which navigates to the inital view-model depending on the platform.

In Core library:

```
 public class CustomAppStart
        : MvxNavigatingObject
        , IMvxAppStart
    {
        public void Start(object hint = null)
        {
           var platform == GetRunningPlatform();
           switch(platform)
           { 
              case Platform.WinStore:
                   ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>();
                   break;
              case Platform.WinPhone:
                   ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>();
                   break;               
              ...    
        }
    }
```

In order to detect which platform the app is running on, there are again few ways to do it.
Check [How can I detect the platform at runtime using MvvMCross?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122318/how-can-i-detect-the-platform-at-runtime-using-mvvmcross) or how MvvmLight is doing it: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/onovotny/MvvmLightPortable/changeset/view/f356af74426f#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/Portable/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/Helpers/DesignerPlatformLibrary.cs

Another idea is to have separate WinPhoneAppStart and WinStoreAppStart on each platform. Note that the custom app start (IMvxAppStart) needs to be registered before the IMvxApplication is created.

In Windows Store App:

```
public class WinStoreAppStart : MvxNavigatingObject, IMvxAppStart
{
    public void Start(object hint = null)
    {
       ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>();   
    }  
}

public class Setup : MvxStoreSetup
{ 
     protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
     {
         Mvx.RegisterType(typeof(IMvxAppStart), typeof(WinStoreAppStart));
         return new Core.App();
     } 
}
```

Phew, I hope this helps you. Let me know if you need more info.

**EDIT:**

**If the 3 pages do not represent the starting main page**, then one idea I have is to use a custom presenter: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#wiki-custom-presenters

In the WinStore app, you can catch navigation to FirstViewModel and instead create the MainViewModel.

Another idea:

You can have a platform dependent controller which implements view-model navigation.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Custom AppStart or separate app start's would do the trick but only at the beginning of the app (app start:). What if I would like similar behaviour later on during navigation, let's say to have separate navigation between pages 7, 8 and 9 on mobile vs one navigation to "big page" containing content 7,8 and 9 on metro app using the same Core project?

Comment: I edit my response to include this scenario as well. Mark as answer if you think it's what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely although you will need to write some custom classes.  If you write a custom presenter for each platform you can use the concept of regions where your views can indicate what region they wish to be displayed in so that when ShowViewModel is called your custom presenter can check if a specific region is requested by the appropriate view and handle as necessary.

Take a look at Stuart Lodges n+1 on custom presenters. Also google "MVVMCross region presenters". You should find some helpful material.

Cheers,
Tristan